# hive parseexception cannot recognize input near 'show' <eof>

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have just installed hive but it is not working. I am
getting a

> ParseException failed/error

when I log into Hive and try to do a show database query in my localhost directory.

[image: hive]

Comment: Next time - no pictures. Text only.

Answer (score 0):

```
show databases;
```

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ShowDatabases

```
hive> show databases;
OK
default
local_db
Time taken: 0.162 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
hive>
```

Answer (score -1):

Execute command :

```
show databases;
```

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7pPA.png)

Comment: please explain your answer